# How to have dots at pager for my Recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-canvas

I have to assign dots at pager to my Recycler view . I already obtained a rectangular pager, but I need to have circles. How can I modify my source to obtain what I need? I've tried some web solutions but no one works for me, and I know that I can obtain this with ViewPager but I need to have this with RecyclerView in this way.
This is my java code for rectangular pager :

```
    public class LinePagerIndicatorDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int colorActive = 0xFFC8C8C8;
private int colorInactive = 0xFFE0E0E0;

    private static final float DP = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    /**
     * Height of the space the indicator takes up at the bottom of the view.
     */
    private final int mIndicatorHeight = (int) (DP * 16);

    /**
     * Indicator stroke width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorStrokeWidth = DP * 2;

    /**
     * Indicator width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 16;
    /**
     * Padding between indicators.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemPadding = DP * 8;

    /**
     * Some more natural animation interpolation
     */
    private final Interpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public LinePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mIndicatorStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
        float totalLength = mIndicatorItemLength * itemCount;
        float paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * mIndicatorItemPadding;
        float indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems;
        float indicatorStartX = (parent.getWidth() - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2F;

        // center vertically in the allotted space
        float indicatorPosY = parent.getHeight() - mIndicatorHeight / 2F;

        drawInactiveIndicators(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount);


        // find active page (which should be highlighted)
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
        int activePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }

        // find offset of active page (if the user is scrolling)
        final View activeChild = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(activePosition);
        int left = activeChild.getLeft();
        int width = activeChild.getWidth();

        // on swipe the active item will be positioned from [-width, 0]
        // interpolate offset for smooth animation
        float progress = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(left * -1 / (float) width);

        drawHighlights(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition, progress, itemCount);
    }

    private void drawInactiveIndicators(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY, int itemCount) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorInactive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        float start = indicatorStartX;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            // draw the line for every item
            c.drawLine(start, indicatorPosY, start + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            start += itemWidth;
        }
    }

    private void drawHighlights(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY,
                                int highlightPosition, float progress, int itemCount) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorActive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        if (progress == 0F) {
            // no swipe, draw a normal indicator
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,
                    highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
        } else {
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            // calculate partial highlight
            float partialLength = mIndicatorItemLength * progress;

            // draw the cut off highlight
            c.drawLine(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY,
                    highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);

            // draw the highlight overlapping to the next item as well
            if (highlightPosition < itemCount - 1) {
                highlightStart += itemWidth;
                c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,
                        highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = mIndicatorHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u plz specify your requirement clearly, Are u using RecyclerView in view Pager ???

Comment: I want to obtain dots for page indicator . With the upside source java code I obtained rectangular page indicator

Comment: alright , so you're getting rectangular indicator with stroke . . .right??

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat yes actually

Comment: there are multiple changes , first in your drawInactiveIndicator method replace c.drawLine(start, indicatorPosY, start + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint); with this line
                c.drawCircle(start,indicatorPosY,(mIndicatorItemLength-start)/2,mPaint);

Comment: in drawHighlights method replace  c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,
                        highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);  with this line 
                c.drawCircle(highlightStart,indicatorPosY,(mIndicatorItemLength-highlightStart)/2,mPaint);

Comment: replace c.drawLine(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY,
                        highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint); with this line 
                c.drawCircle(highlightStart + partialLength,indicatorPosY,(mIndicatorItemLength-highlightStart + partialLength)/2,mPaint);

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat that's all?

Comment: try this change first only ,if you found any changes, we'll go further , first change is in your drawInactiveIndicator method replace c.drawLine(start, indicatorPosY, start + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint); with this line c.drawCircle(start,indicatorPosY,(mIndicatorItemLength)/2,mPaint);

Comment: it does not work, maybe i wrong something. Please can you post My souce code with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class temp extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int colorActive = 0xFFC8C8C8;
    private int colorInactive = 0xFFE0E0E0;

    private static final float DP = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    /**
     * Height of the space the indicator takes up at the bottom of the view.
     */
    private final int mIndicatorHeight = (int) (DP * 16);

    /**
     * Indicator stroke width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorStrokeWidth = DP * 2;

    /**
     * Indicator width.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemLength = DP * 16;
    /**
     * Padding between indicators.
     */
    private final float mIndicatorItemPadding = DP * 8;

    /**
     * Some more natural animation interpolation
     */
    private final Interpolator mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public LinePagerIndicatorDecoration() {
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mIndicatorStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
        float totalLength = mIndicatorItemLength * itemCount;
        float paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * mIndicatorItemPadding;
        float indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems;
        float indicatorStartX = (parent.getWidth() - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2F;

        // center vertically in the allotted space
        float indicatorPosY = parent.getHeight() - mIndicatorHeight / 2F;

        drawInactiveIndicators(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount);


        // find active page (which should be highlighted)
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager();
        int activePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }

        // find offset of active page (if the user is scrolling)
        final View activeChild = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(activePosition);
        int left = activeChild.getLeft();
        int width = activeChild.getWidth();

        // on swipe the active item will be positioned from [-width, 0]
        // interpolate offset for smooth animation
        float progress = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(left * -1 / (float) width);

        drawHighlights(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition, progress, itemCount);
    }

    private void drawInactiveIndicators(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY, int itemCount) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorInactive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        float start = indicatorStartX;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            // draw the line for every item
            //    c.drawLine(start, indicatorPosY, start + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            c.drawCircle(start, indicatorPosY, (mIndicatorItemLength) / 2, mPaint);
            start += itemWidth;
        }
    }

    private void drawHighlights(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY,
                                int highlightPosition, float progress, int itemCount) {
        mPaint.setColor(colorActive);

        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = mIndicatorItemLength + mIndicatorItemPadding;

        if (progress == 0F) {
            // no swipe, draw a normal indicator
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            //    c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            c.drawCircle(highlightStart, indicatorPosY, (mIndicatorItemLength) / 2, mPaint);
        } else {
            float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
            // calculate partial highlight
            float partialLength = mIndicatorItemLength * progress;

            // draw the cut off highlight
            //    c.drawLine(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY,highlightStart + mIndicatorItemLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
            c.drawCircle(highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, (mIndicatorItemLength) / 2, mPaint);

            // draw the highlight overlapping to the next item as well
            if (highlightPosition < itemCount - 1) {
                highlightStart += itemWidth;
                //    c.drawLine(highlightStart, indicatorPosY,highlightStart + partialLength, indicatorPosY, mPaint);
                c.drawCircle(highlightStart, indicatorPosY, (mIndicatorItemLength) / 2, mPaint);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = mIndicatorHeight;
    }
}
```

give it a try,hope this will work.

Comment: This does not work :(, the interpreter give me 3 errors

Comment: I solved all. This Works fine thank you very much bro

Comment: Can you take a give up to my quest? :)

Comment: I only have a problem it is not centered to Recycler view it is a little bit on left...Why?

Comment: It's an xml related issue can't commmet on this without checking the layout file

Comment: Great , happy coding:)

Comment: RTL support for the same?